# Copy files from last 5 days[BASH]

Tags: bash

hey fellow bash scripters,

I need some help with a backup script I'm making atm. I'm doing my internship at the moment and I have to backup files if they have been modified within the last 5 days. If someone has a code for me that works also please explain what everything does ;)

Thanks if you are trying to help me!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not here to write your homework assignments for you. Please try solving this and come back with examples of what you tried - and of any errors that you encountered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find such files under a given directory, you can use `find` and its `-mtime` option:

```
find /path -mtime -5
```

`-mtime -5` means "modification time less than 5 days".

To copy the files somewhere, you can combine it with the `-exec` option:

```
find /path -mtime -5 -exec cp -t /target {} +
```

`{}` will be replaced by the file names. `-t /target` specifies the target directory to copy the files to. `+` means `find` can replace `{}` with more than one file.

See `man find` for details.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer and good explanation!

Comment: Plus one for using the GNU find "+" exec option. :)